# How to hide components in Unity Inspector

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a game object in my inspector with a lot of components. Using a custom editor, I have been able to access and collect all of the components in an array. I want to be able to hide those components named "blahblah". This is my code:

```
arryCom = GetComponents(typeof(Component));
    for (int i = 0; i < arryCom.Length; i++)
    {
        if (arryCom [i].GetType ().ToString () == "blahblah")
              arryCom [i].hideFlags = HideFlags.HideInInspector;
    }
```

It doesn't work, and all of components are still visible in the Inspector. What do you think is wrong?

UPDATE:
The game object is a Flowchart (created by an external asset called Fungus). I added the `FlowchartManager` to it:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class FlowchartManager : MonoBehaviour 
{
    private Component[] arryCom;

    public void HideSays()
    {
        arryCom = GetComponents(typeof(Component));
        for (int i = 0; i < arryCom.Length; i++)
        {
            if (arryCom [i].GetType ().ToString () == "blahblah")
                arryCom [i].hideFlags = HideFlags.HideInInspector;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the custom editor:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

[CustomEditor(typeof(FlowchartManager))]
public class FlowchartEditor : Editor
{
    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        //base.OnInspectorGUI();
        FlowchartManager fm = (FlowchartManager)target;
        if (GUILayout.Button ("Hide Says"))
            fm.HideSays ();
    }
}
```

And this screenshot shows that the FlowchartManager script is attached to the game object without any problem:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lQIm.png)

I don't get any compiler errors, btw.

Comment: Your `if` statement is messed up. That should be `if (arryCom[i].GetType().ToString() == "blahblah")`. How do you expect a code that doesn't compile to execute?

Comment: Thanks @Programmer. I corrected it. Still, it doesn't work.

Comment: In that case, include the **complete** script. Since you made that mistake, I suspect there are more of them and your script is not compiling. Also, show the complete code of the `blahblah` script. Finally, a screenshot of the GameObject it is attached to to prove that it is actually attached to an Object. When I say **complete* script, I mean every code in that file. Copy and paste

Comment: done! @Programmer

Comment: Which Object has the `blahblah` script attached to? You also need a  screenshot of the GameObject it is attached to to prove that it is actually attached to an Object

Comment: blahblah is not a script. It is the name of components of the game object (the Flowchart). I want this component not to be shown in the inspector when I click on the Flowchart.

Comment: components can be called scripts in Unity. If you don't have any component/script called "blahblah" then how do you expect that `if` statement to be true?

Comment: Why don't you use `arryCom = GetComponents(typeof(blahblah));` ????
it's do the same thing, but you have to remove `if (arryCom [i].GetType ().ToString () == "blahblah")`

Comment: It seems I can't explain myself well enough, as English is not my mother tongue. I'll try one more time:
I have a GameObject. It's name is "Flowchart". The Flowchart, has, say 50 components. Out of these 50 components, 10 are of the type "blahblah". I want the inspector to hide all of these 10 blahblahs, and  show only 40 other components.

Answer (score 1):

The thing that got me, and I imagine it might have gotten you, is that changing the hideflags doesn't repaint the editor. Components will only hide after you change the selection (or force the panel recreation another way).

Also, instead of

```
foo.GetType().ToString()=="Bar"
```

its better to use

```
foo.GetType()==typeof(Bar)
```